# How to split string from commas(,) and store into separate variables in PHP

Tags: php

I want to know how can I split a string and store that into separate variables. Suppose I have a string "healthy,foody,fitness,food" and now I want to store each value in separate variable. I already converted them into array with explode()

Now how can i store each value in separate variable like say

```
$health = "healthy";
$foody = "foody";
$fitness = "fitness";
```

and so on.

The main purpose of doing this is, I am trying to make an E commerce website with core PHP and I have a value called "tags" in database where i store tags in comma separated values and I have to use those tags for sorting "Similar Products" and that's why I need them in separate variable so that I can

```
"SELECT * FROM products WHERE tags='$health' OR tags='$foody'";
```

You get my point right? All helps appreciated! 
Have a great day!

Comment: _where i store tags in comma separated values..._ The problems start here! never store values comma separated into db... think about normalization

Comment: @B001ᛦ, then how can i implement features like tags and cart?

Comment: _then how can i implement features like tags and cart?..._ I think I already gave you the hint... normalization!

Comment: if you have already an array  .. why you need  the vars name  ???  use the array by index

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find by tags from string, you can do that:

```
$string = "healthy,foody,fitness,food";
$tags = explode(",", $string);
$tags = array_map(function($v) {return "'".trim($v)."'"; }, $tags);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE tags IN(".implode(",", $tags).")";
```

output is:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE tags IN('healthy','foody','fitness','food')
```